# Update query issue in VB and Access

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb6, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to implement the change password module in a application in VB. The update query is having some issues

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
Query = "Select * From Users Where LoginID='" & txtLoginID & "' and Password = '" & txtCuPassword & "'"
 Set reSet = myCon.Execute(Query)

If (Not reSet.BOF) And (Not reSet.EOF) Then
    Query1 = "UPDATE Users SET Password ='" & txtNewPassword & "' WHERE LoginID='" & txtLoginID & "'"
    Set reSet = myCon.Execute(Query1)
```

When executed an error is thrown at UPDATE query, as syntax error.

Comment: @MitchWheat Sorry missed but then also there is no change in the error.

Comment: Does your txtNewPassword contains a single quote?

Comment: By the way, the code above seems to be VB6 or VBA, but you have tagged Visual-Studio-2010. Something is not right there.

Comment: Good old [little Bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)... @Jeyaprakash Learn how to sanitise your database input. If anyone enters a ' then your whole query breaks again, or your database is compromised.

Answer (score 2):

So, if your code has a single quote in the txtNewPassword field, your query ends up something like this

```
Query = "UPDATE Users SET Password ='mypass'word' WHERE LoginID='123'"
```

and this, of course is a syntax error.

You could try to replace a single quote with a pair of single quotes

```
Query = "UPDATE Users SET [Password] ='" & Replace(txtNewPassword, "'", "''") & "' WHERE ....
```

But remember that this code is open wide to SQL Injection. You should use parametrized queries also if it is not really easy to do that in VB6. Also, as pointed out by HansUp in its comment, you need to enclose the reserved word `Password` with square brackets

[Why should I use Parameters instead of putting values into my SQL string](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?548787-Database-Why-should-I-use-Parameters-instead-of-putting-values-into-my-SQL-string)

Comment: It is much easier to always prefix with a table name, or better, alias than to bracket reserved words. The prefix means the word is unambiguous and so you do not have to bracket. Furthermore, it will work well with other databases and ensure you do not end up with an error from having two fields of the same name in a query.